# FileReader cannot read from resource folder Java when exported

Tags: java, eclipse, bufferedreader

I'm making a top-down shooter game, but I cannot seem to load the world when the jar is exported.

Making a new world:

```
world = new World(handler, "res/worlds/world1.txt");
```

that loads the world in World constructor:

```
loadWorld(path);
```

loadWorld function contains this line:

```
String file = Utils.loadFileAsString(path);
```

and thereon I'll load all the content of the file to an int[][] array and go on

In Utils class I have this code:

```
public static String loadFileAsString(String path) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "File Loaded (Dev testing)");
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            b.append(line + "\n");
        br.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return b.toString();
}
```

But it gets stuck on the

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
```

part, because the JOptionPane window doesn't show up.

**It works when running it in Eclipse but not when exported as a Runnable Jar File.**

Image of my exported jar file opened in 7zip: [http://imgur.com/AX240ha](https://imgur.com/AX240ha)

Any help will be appreciated!

Regads,
Kerdo K.

Comment: the JOptionPane is not showing, but is there no IOException being thrown? Somehow I think there is no **file** `res/worlds/world1.txt` in the same directory as the jar.

Answer (score 2):

Your program will search for the worlds folder in the directory whereever the .jar is placed. But since the worlds folder is inside the jar, it won't be found. So you have the following two solutions:

- Move the worlds folder outside your jar
- Load the data from inside the jar using special code like the following:

  ```
  InputStream input = World.class.getResourceAsStream("/worlds/world1.txt");
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
  ```

If you only want to send a single jar file to other people, you should go with the second option. But if you use a platform like Steam or even a simple Installer, you should use the first option.

Note, that when you choose the second option, the code might only work in Eclipse if you make the *res* folder a source folder (right-click on the *res* folder: *Build Path > Use as Source Folder*).

Comment: I would make the decision of having the file in the jar depending if it need to be changed or not. And the second option should work with eclipse.

Comment: Got it working, forgot to remove "/res" from the path. Thanks!

Comment: Having it like this:
`world = new World(handler, "/worlds/world1.txt");`

Comment: Make sure you don't forget the slash at the beginning. That one stumped me a lot...

Comment: If you place the resource in the same package as the World class, the initial slash isn’t necessary.  In fact, this will be required as of Java 9, if your .jar file is module aware.